# Google Adsense com CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou tentando colocar um banner adsense no CakePHP e nao estou conseguindo, o banner simplesmente não aparece. Como fazer isso ?

**footer.ctp**

```
<footer>
<?php echo $this->fetch('script');?>

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXX"
             data-ad-slot="5082072999"
             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que estava vendo na documentação existem um problema:

> Pode ser necessário aguardar até 48 horas para que os anúncios do
>   Google sejam exibidos e até uma semana para que o AdSense para
>   pesquisas comece a funcionar em seus sites, enquanto atualizamos os
>   nossos servidores com a mudança de status de sua conta. Agradecemos
>   sua paciência.

Não seria este o problema ?

Comment: será ? tomara que sim, vou aguardar e qquer coisa posto aqui, obrigado.

Comment: Da uma verificada se seu codigo esta sendo "plotado" no html estando la o problema seria esse  "tempo" de espera